# How to download a html table with inconsistent number of columns in R?

Tags: html, r, excel, rvest

I´m currently trying to download a table from the following URL:

```
url1<-"http://iambweb.ams.or.at/ambweb/showcognusServlet?tabkey=3643193&regionDisplay=%C3%96sterreich&export=html&outputLocale=de"
```

I downloaded and saved the file as .xls because I thought it is a Excel-file with the following code:

```
temp <- paste0(tempfile(), ".xls")
download.file(url1, destfile = temp, mode = "wb")
```

First I tried to read it in R as a Excel file but it seems to be a html (can be read by Excel though):

```
dfAMS <- read_excel(path = temp, sheet = "Sheet1", range = "I7:I37")
```

Therefore:

```
df <- read_html(temp)
```

Now unfortunately I´m stuck because the following lines of code won´t give me the intended result (a nice table or at least column I7:I37 in the .xls):

```
dfAMS <- html_node(df, "table") %>% html_table(fill = T) %>% tibble::as_tibble()
dplyr::glimpse(df)
```

I´m pretty sure the solution is rather simple but I´m currently stuck and can´t find a solution...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried the `skip = n` Option but still get the same structure...

Comment: There appears to be something corrupt in the downloaded file.  I downloaded and resaved the file in Excel and then I was able to read the file with `read_xls` function from the `readxl` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klamsi, the url points to an html file renamed to have a ".xls" extension. This is somewhat common practice among webmasters. Try it yourself by renaming the ".xls" extention to ".html".

A second problem is that the html has a very messy table configuration. The table of interest is the fifth table in the document.

This is a workaround to obtain the values for the overall population (or "range A7:B37, I7:K37")

```
url <- "http://iambweb.ams.or.at/ambweb/showcognusServlet?tabkey=3643193&regionDisplay=%C3%96sterreich&export=html&outputLocale=en"

df <- read_html(url) %>%
      html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE) %>% 
      .[[5]] %>% #Extract the fifth table in the list
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      .[,c(1:11)] %>% 
      select(1:2, 9:11)

names <- unlist(df[1,])
names[1:2] <- c("item", "Bundesland")
colnames(df) <- names
df <- df[-1,]

df %>% head()

  item              Bundesland Bestand Veränderung zum VJ absolut Veränderung zum VJ in %
2 Arbeitslosigkeit       Bgld    7119                       -973      -0.120242214532872
3 Arbeitslosigkeit        Ktn   16564                      -2160      -0.115359965819269
4 Arbeitslosigkeit         NÖ   46342                      -6095      -0.116234719758949
5 Arbeitslosigkeit         OÖ   29762                      -4649      -0.135102147569091
6 Arbeitslosigkeit        Sbg   11173                       -643     -0.0544177386594448
7 Arbeitslosigkeit       Stmk   28677                      -5602        -0.1634236704688
```